# Search an integer value from one field in another (varchar) field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to query the records from my database that contain the value from an id field (integer) - 1000 in the string contained in another (varchar) field, e.g.

```
id   |  title 
----------------------------------
2313 | This is text no. 1313
3745 | This is text no. 2745
```

This query kind of works for me:

```
SELECT * 
FROM texts 
WHERE title LIKE '%' || id - 1000 || '%'
```

It shows records like the ones above, but others, too, where the numerical value contained in the 'title' field is identical to the one contained in the "id" field, like this:

```
id   |  title 
----------------------------------
913  | This is text no. 913
7767 | This is text no. 7767
```

Can I compute field values in a LIKE comparison? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you try converting id - 1000 to string first? Sorry, I don't know the exact syntax for that in postgre

Comment: Your query does not return IDs 913 or 7767: http://rextester.com/HKG78869 - there must be something else you are not telling us.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Alexandr Kapshuk! I've tried your suggestion, too, with a function I've copied from a question at stackoverflow that converts integers into text, but I got the same result.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need to write any function to convert an integer to a string, `(id - 1000)::text` will do just fine (but that's not necessary with the query you have shown)

Comment: Thanks, @ a_horse_with_no_name! I had tried the casting, too, but the query did not give the result I wanted, so I tried the function. Obviously the casting was not to blame for the wrong result.

Comment: Obviously I was applying the wrong logic!!! If a substract 1000 from the value and cast it as text, I will be getting a substring of the intended value for values between 1001 and 1999! I will have to use regex! Sorry for the inconveniences!